# Is this sentence below grammatical?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Emotions like Governor Malloy’s and mine seem primal—hardwired
into us, reflexively deployed, shared with all our fellow humans. When triggered, they seem to unleash themselves in each of us in basically the same way.**My sadness was like Governor Malloy’s sadness was like the crowd’s sadness.**

I thought in English there can not be two predicates without “and” linking them.

Comment: There is not enough context to comment. It could be *My sadness was {like Governor Malloy’s sadness was like the crowd’s sadness.}*, which is wrong or *My sadness was {like Governor Malloy’s sadness}, was like the crowd’s sadness.* which is right but poetic/literary and has the comma as a conjunctive comma.

Comment: This would probably be a schoolboy/girl error in a child's essay, but would be considered extragrammatical rather than ungrammatical, trendsetting,  in writing considered as quality writing (which this probably is ... you should add a link, an attribution, and a couple of surrounding sentences). I've met 'A is [like] B is [like] C', 'A likes B likes C' sentences before, and they're intended to be somewhat startling.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It’s from a bestseller, How Emotions Are Made.

Comment: It gets a lot of praise and 'well written's from critics. Extragrammatical, not an error. _But use this construction with great care._ Dashes etc often add some respectability to say subject deletion: 'My sadness was like Governor Malloy’s sadness ... was like the crowd’s sadness.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you!

Comment: It's basically saying that all three sadnesses are like each other.